# Finding the max and min values for a surface on region R

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Surface $$\ f(x,y)=x^2+4y^2-x+2y$$
 on the region bounded by 
$$\ x^2+4y^2=1 $$

Finding the critical points of the surface within the region was easy enough, I found a minimum at $\ (\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{4})$. What I'm having trouble with is finding the critical points along the boundary. I can plug in the equation for the region into the surface equation, but that leaves me with a square root.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\cos t,y=\frac12\sin t$, which satisfies the equation of the boundary. Then

$$f(x(t),y(t))=1-\cos t+\sin t$$

and the derivative can be expressed as the dot product

$$(1,1)\cdot(\cos t,\sin t)=\sqrt2\cos\theta$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

The extreme values are obtained with $t=\pm\frac\pi4$.

---

**Your solution:**

$$x=\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}$$ and

$$f(x(y),y)=1\mp\sqrt{1-4y^2}+2y.$$

Canceling the derivative,

$$\pm\frac{2y}{\sqrt{1-4y^2}}+1=0$$

or

$$\frac{4y^2}{1-4y^2}=1,$$

which is

$$y=\pm\frac1{\sqrt8}$$ and $$x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $f(x,y) = 1-x+2y$, and using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $(-x+2y)^2 = (1\cdot (-x)+1\cdot (2y))^2\leq (1^2+1^2)(x^2+4y^2)=2$. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: We haven't covered the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Is that the only means of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+4y^2=1$ is an ellipse. If $g(t)$ is the parametrization of the ellipse, then $f(g(t))$ are the values of $f$ along the ellipse (the boundary). At that point you are left with a single variable optimization problem.